# can't get string conversion strtod in c

Tags: c, strtod

Could somebody help me(sorry for the english), Im trying to convert a string to a double but when I can't get it here's my code(thank you, I'll appreciate help so much):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define MAX_LONG 5

char bx[MAX_LONG];
double cali=0;

int main() {
scanf("%c",bx);
cali = strtod(bx,NULL);
printf("%f",cali);
return 0;
}
```

when I input a value greater than 10 in the output it just print the first number like this:

```
 input: 23
 output: 2.00000
 input: 564
 output: 5.00000
```

Comment: Why don't you use `scanf("%lf", &cali)`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `scanf()` specifier you are using is wrong, unless you specify a number of characters, but then the array will not be `nul` terminated, I suggest the following

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main() 
{
    char   bx[6]; /* if you want 5 characters, need an array of 6
                   * because a string needs a `nul' terminator byte
                   */
    double cali;
    char  *endptr;

    if (scanf("%5s", bx) != 1)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "`scanf()' unexpected error.\n");
        return -1;
    }

    cali = strtod(bx, &endptr);
    if (*endptr != '\0')
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "cannot convert, `%s' to `double'\n", bx);
        return -1;
    }        
    printf("%f\n", cali);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much I'll implement this code in my program (:

Comment: this is great (I'm trying to understand this is my first program ) Thanks

Comment: You need to read the manuals or standard specification for the functions to really learn how to used them, for example `scanf()` is misused in many books.

Comment: Ok, I'll download one

Comment: I ran the code but it doesn't work always print  "`scanf()' unexpected error." :c

Comment: @user2461687 I am sorry.. I typed `==` by mistake.

Comment: @iharob Note that your second `fprintf()` causes undefined behaviour. (You have `%s` but no other arguments.)

Comment: thank you, I just need to change scanf("%s",bx) from your code, it´s working now I can get done my homework C:

Comment: @user2461687 **Do not** use `scanf("%s", bx);` be cause you might overflow the `bx` buffer, it may seem to work, but it could suddenly break because it's not working, if it does is just because you are lucky. Increase the size of `bx`, and change `"%5s"` to `"%Ns` where `N` should be the number of elements of `bx` minus 1.

Answer (score 0):

You should try this changes to make it work.

First: 
Change

```
scanf("%c",bx); /*Here you're reading a single char*/
```

To this:

```
scanf("%s",bx);/*Now you're reading a full string (No spaces)*/
```

Second:
Change

```
cali = strtod(bx,NULL);
```

To this:

```
cali = atof(bx);
```

This i think will work perferct For you.

Comment: You generally do not want to discourage someone from using a function such as `strtod` that provides far superior error checking in the event of a conversion failure than does `atof` which provides ..... none. You want to help them understand how to properly check the results of `errno`, the value of `endptr` and whether a **high/low infinite value** was returned.